# Questions about relative in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a file structure like this:
[image]

Just for the demo, please ignore other issue. Like try to access json file from html.

Say I want to access data/employees.json file both from js/test.html and js/widget.js

As you can see, both test.html and widget.js are at the same folder.

And I link widget.js in the index.html file

`<script src="js/widget.js"></script>`

As I always thought, if I want to access data/employees.json from files from js folder, I use relative path, in this case, for widget.js , I wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log(window.location);
  $.getJSON('../data/employees.json', function (data) {
    //some code here
  }); // end getJSON
}); // end ready
```

for test.html, I wrote this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../data/employees.json">
```

The console gives me no error for test.html, but the code in widget.js has a 404 error.

SO my question is, now I am in widget.js file, I want to access employees.json file. What's the correct relative path I should use if widget.js in linked at the index.html in the root folder? Why?

It looks to me, the widget.js and test.html are at the same level and should use the same path for the employees.json, that is "../data/employees.json"

Thanks.

Comment: the path needs to be relative to the html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct path to employees.js depends on the path of the page that wants to load it, not the path of the script doing the loading. From your index.html file, the path to employees.js is "data/employees.js". From test.html, the path is "../data/employees.js".

You will need some way to figure out where you are in the structure of the site and make the correct request.

The easiest way to do this is to store those files in a well-known location, then use absolute URLs - i.e., "/data/employees.js". Then, no matter where you're trying to load from, the path is always starting from the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.getJSON('/../data/employees.json', function (data) {
```

Relative URLs are interpreted relative to the directory of the page containing the reference.

Or:

```
jQuery.getJSON('//www.domain.com/whatever/theJson.json', function(data){
```